# format-date function in xslt issue

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, formatdatetime

I am working on a homework task to create an XSL stylesheet that retrieves the data from the XML file given by my teacher and use the format-date function in XSLT.

I am trying to format a date in this format:

Thursday 26 April

here is what my xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="weather-1.xsl"?>
<product version="1.7" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.bom.gov.au/schema/v1.7/product.xsd">
    <forecast>
        <area aac="NSW_FA001" description="New South Wales" type="region">
            <forecast-period start-time-local="2018-04-26T04:30:02+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-26T04:30:02+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-25T18:30:02Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-25T18:30:02Z">
                <text type="synoptic_situation">
                    <p>A low pressure trough off the New South Wales north coast is weakening as a high pressure system south of the Bight moves very slowly east extending a ridge along the coast. The high is expected to move over the southern Tasman by Wednesday maintaining the ridge to the north.</p>
                </text>
                <text type="warning_summary_footer">Details of warnings are available on the Bureau's website www.bom.gov.au, by telephone 1300-659-218* or through some TV and radio broadcasts.</text>
                <text type="product_footer">* Calls to 1300 numbers cost around 27.5c incl. GST, higher from mobiles or public phones.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2018-04-26T05:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-25T19:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="fire_danger">Very High: Northwestern fire area.</text>
                <text type="forecast">Medium chance of showers along the northern half of the coast with the risk of thunderstorms. The chance of afternoon thunderstorms in the northern inland. Early fog in the east. Partly cloudy elsewhere. Daytime temperatures close to average. Winds south to southwesterly, freshening along the coast and about the central west slopes.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2018-04-27T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-26T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">A shower or two in the east, more likely about the north coast. The chance of a thunderstorm in the far northeast. Early frost patches about the southern ranges. Fine and mostly sunny in the west. Daytime temperatures below average, especially in the southeast. South to southeasterly winds, freshening about the northeast and along the coast.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2018-04-28T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-27T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Showers in the east, more likely about the central and northern coastal fringe. Fine and mostly sunny elsewhere. Early frost patches about the southern ranges. Daytime temperatures below average in the east and about average elsewhere. South to southeasterly winds, freshening about the north coast.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2018-04-29T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2018-04-30T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2018-04-28T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2018-04-29T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Showers in the east, more likely about the central and north coast. Fine and mostly sunny elsewhere. Early frost patches about the southern ranges. Daytime temperatures below average in the east, about average elsewhere. South to southeasterly winds.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
    </forecast>
</product>
```

And this is my XSL stylesheet I have currently:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="product[1]">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>State Weather</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>NSW and ACT Weather</h3>
                <p>Forecast for the rest of <xsl:value-of select="format-date(forecast/area/forecast-period[@start-time-local],'[FNn] [D1] [MNn]')"/></p>
                <p><xsl:value-of select="forecast/area/forecast-period[2]/text[2]"/></p>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using a http python server to test my stylesheet. To see weather it displays the correct information.

This is the result that I am aiming to achieve:

[image]

I did various google searching on how to implement and use the format-date function but I am still confused to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Well, which result do you get? Are you sure you use an XSLT 2 processor? The `format-date(forecast/area/forecast-period[@start-time-local]` should be `format-date(forecast/area/forecast-period/@start-time-local` if you want to format the attribute value.

Comment: When something fails, always tell us HOW it fails. Looking at the failure symptoms is always the first step in problem solving.

Comment: Well its kind of hard to know how it fails since I am using a http python server and the only way I am editting my xsl is through notepadd++

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the attribute value with the dateTime value and as it is a dateTime you need to use `format-dateTime` and not `format-date`.

A minimal example is

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(/product/forecast/area/forecast-period/@start-time-local, '[FNn] [D1] [MNn]')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

which outputs `Thursday 26 April`.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2C5/1 has a working sample.

Of course you need to use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor like Saxon 9. I am not aware of that being supported in the context of Python although Saxon 9 C should allow that in principle.

Comment: I was able to find a way to use saxon9 through command line and execute my stylesheet

Comment: I tired your code and I get this error message


Type error at char 17 in xsl:value-of/@select on line 13 column 123 of weather-1.xsl:
XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of


  fn:format-dateTime() (2018-04-26T04:30:02+10:00, 2018-04-26T05:00:00+10:00)
  in built-in template rule for /product in the unnamed mode


A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:form
at-dateTime() (2018-04-26T04:30:02+10:00, 2018-04-26T05:00:00+10:00)

Comment: Well. I have given you a small sample to demonstrate the use of the `format-dateTime` function against one instance of your sample data, to get the desired output, as you seemed to be struggling to use that function at all. Obviously, if you want format a sequence of values then you need a completely different approach like setting up a tempate with `match="forecast-period"` where you then simply use `format-dateTime(@start-time-local, '[FNn] [D1] [MNn]')`.

Comment: Or as a quick shot to only return a sequence of formatted values based on the previous example you can use `/product/forecast/area/forecast-period/format-dateTime(@start-time-local, '[FNn] [D1] [MNn]')` to avoid that error. But you might want to take some time to read a chapter on the processing model of XSLT in https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm, then you are better equipped to write code against XML input structures that is modular and decomposed in small, managable unites.

Comment: Well I tried to be more specific with where to call the start-time-local, so I added [index='0'] next to the forecast-period to see that works but I have an unclosed attribute error

Comment: I also tried the /product/forecast/area/forecast-period/format-dateTime(@start-time-local, '[FNn] [D1] [MNn]') as you mentioned to get rid of the previous error but again that did not work either

Comment: I think the use of  `format-dateTime` to format your attribute values in the desired format is solved with the suggestions made, see it in action at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2C5/2. As I said, writing complete stylesheets to create a certain layout (where then one small detail might be having a date in a particular format) is a completely different problem, start with a introduction to the processing model in a tutorial or text book and take it step by step, you can then, on each step you get stuck, ask a specific question, with a clear description of what went wrong.